# "Accuracy" function in "forecast" package of R 3.0.2

Tags: r, macos, forecast

I installed R version 3.0.2 on Mac OS X 10.8.4, then tried to install "forecast" package using `install.package("forecast")`

However, although the `packageVersion("forecast")` shows me the 4.8 version (which means it is installed) and the *accuracy* function is well described in forecast package version 4.8 document (http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/forecast/forecast.pdf), I cannot use *accuracy* function and when I use help function, this is the response:

```
> help("accuracy")

no documentation for ‘accuracy’ in specified packages and libraries:
you could try ‘??accuracy’
```

Could anyone help me with the problem in installation?

Answer (score 1):

You need to load the package before you can use it or before you can view the help file without specifying the package

```
library(forecast) # or require(forecast)
help("accuracy")
# or
?accuracy
```

If you don't want to load the library you can just specify the package

```
help("accuracy", package = "forecast")
```

but in general just installing the package doesn't load it automatically.